magento oauth request_token returns Net::HTTPRetriableError: 302 "Found"
I am using oauth 1 to connect allow users to authorize their Magento store. I keep getting Net::HTTPRetriableError: 302 "Found" when requesting a token.
To confirm, site is our magento admin site where we created the integration? It is not the store url that the user wants to sign in to correct?
     4: def self.initiate_oauth
     5:   callback_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/oauth/callback"
     6:   key = "key"
     7:   secret = "secret"
     8:   oauth_consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(key, secret, {
     9:     request_token_path: '/oauth/initiate',
    10:     access_token_path: '/oauth/token',
    11:     authorize_path: '/admin/oauth_authorize',
    12:     access_token_path: '/oauth/token',
    13:     site: "https://my_site.com"
    14:   })
    15:   callback_url = "https://my_app/oauth_callback"
    16:   request_token = oauth_consumer.get_request_token(callback_url: callback_url)
    17: 
    18: rescue StandardError => e
 => 19:   binding.pry
    20: end

[1] pry(MagentoManager::MagentoOauth)> e
=> #<Net::HTTPRetriableError: 302 "Found">

